# Textfield too long for docker?

Tags: python, django, docker

I am currently updating an old website (running on Django 1.3) to the newer version (Django 1.10). My boss suggested I use Docker, because it would be easier to deploy with it, so now we're using Django + Docker + Gunicorn + Nginx (before it was just Django and Apache).
We have a model called Article that keeps the content of the website. Content is a TextField. One of the Articles is a table, containing a list of shops. This article is quite long, over 65000 characters.
The problem is, only the first 64416 chars are displayed if we run it inside of Docker. If I try running gunicorn directly on my laptop it's ok (entire page loads) and the same code ran from inside of the Docker container results in the truncated data.
What's even more confusing, I ran

```
manage.py shell
```

and

```
Article.objects.get(id=16)
```

it returns the entire content, but

```
Article.object.get(id=16).content
```

gives once again only the first 64416 chars. 
My docker image is based on Alpine 3.3, my host os is Linux 16.10.
What is the reason for this behavior? What's wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify the Python versions used on your laptop and inside the container? Also, what is the host that the Docker container is running on?

Comment: It's Python 2.7 on both, host system is Ubuntu 16.10.